# Deleting files doesn't clear hard drive space, adds to "hidden space", "Other" taking up over 600GB of SSD. First Aid causes errors as well

Tags: hard-drive, backup, time-machine, ssd, apfs

Pretty sure I'm experiencing the effects of a hard drive on its last legs or requiring a fresh install of OSX, but have some roadblocks in my way that are preventing that. Here's my situation.

Mid 2014 Retina MBP 15" on 10.13.6

Noticed a couple weeks ago that deleting files wasn't actually clearing hard drive space, used DaisyDisk, Omni Disk Sweeper, and Grand Perspective to try to figure out what was going on.

They all show some variation of 350-400GB of "Hidden Space" that I cannot access (after running every program as administrator/sudo)

When running first aid on the internal SSD (Macintosh HD) I'm getting the error

```
Checking the snapshot metadata tree
error: btn:1: invalid key order (23) oid 1362952 / oxid 21616861
Sanpshot metadata tree is invalid.
The volume /dev/rdisk2s1 could not be verified completely.
File system check exit code is 0.
```

From what I understand this doesn't seem to be a great situation. I tried running /sbin/fsck -fy from single user mode (cmd+s on startup) but I was given the same error every time (ran it 4 or 5 times to make sure it was working). I've also tried the `sudo tmutil listLocalSnapshots /` command that I've seen around this forum, but nothing shows up when I run the command. Not sure if this is related at all, but also noticed my computer's serial number is showing up as "Unavailable" as well.

Other than that I'm sort of at a loss of what to do. I have some backups that aren't entirely recent but I'd like to be able to back my computer up before wiping it and reinstalling the OS if possible. Problem is I only have 5GB left on the hard drive and deleting data barely reclaims space. Deleting 80GB of data gave me about 0.25GB of useable space, the rest goes to "Hidden Space". Unfortunately, the low amount of space left on the hard drive is making it impossible for Time Machine to backup my computer as it requires some space on the source drive to conduct the backup.

If anyone has any suggestions it would be greatly appreciated. Happy to answer any questions you have about the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried running First Aid?

Comment: Just to make sure - by 'deleting' you do mean throwing in the Trash then emptying the Trash?

Comment: If you're still trying to salvage the data, I would first try booting from an Ubuntu USB and seeing if [`apfs-fuse`](https://github.com/sgan81/apfs-fuse) has any luck mounting your drive.